# Using if and while to accept elements in an array

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, while-loop

I wrote a program that has **an array of 4 elements** and accept only numbers **from 1 to 4 (1,2,3,
4)** and each time I prompt the user to give an input (only 1,2,3,4) and each time I check if the array already has this input or not ... if it has this element so the user must provide another number if not then store the element in the array.

here is my code : -

```
import java.util.*;
public class Arr{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] arr = new int[4];
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number;
        while(arr.length < 5){
            System.out.print("Enter a number from 1-4 : ");
            number = sc.nextInt();
            if(number <= 0 || number > 4){
                System.out.print("Rejected ! Please re-enter a number from 1-4 : ");
            }
            else{
                for(int j = 0 ; j < arr.length ; j++){
                    if(number == arr[j]){
                        System.out.print("Already exists .. enter new number from 1-4 : ");
                        number  = sc.nextInt();
                    }
                    else{
                        arr[j]=number;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but something goes **wrong logically** and i can't figure it out ... **Help** ?

Comment: Multiple things are wrong: `arr.length` does not change because arrays have a fixed length, you'll need to count the valid inputs. Furthermore after the "already exists" error you want to enter the next loop iteration, not read another number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while(arr.length < 5){
```

As you are using an array, it has a **fixed size.** `arr.length` will *always* be 4. For the same reason, you will also have to keep track of how many array elements are "filled".

```
if(number <= 0 || number > 4){
```

You should use a `while` or a `do-while` loop instead to keep repeating the prompt until the user enters the correct input.

```
arr[j]=number;
```

That is going to set the first non-matching array element to the input number. I'm sure that's *not* what you want.

If you are a beginner, it will be a good idea to write out a plan of how the program should function:

> Ask user for input.
>   Check input if between 1 to 4.
>   Repeat asking user until valid input provided.
>   On valid input, check array if input already exists.
>   If yes, alert user and ask for input again.
>   If no, store input in the next available slot in array.

Then build a pseudocode out of it. Example:

```
have counter to track position in array (initialize to 0)
do
    get input
    if input >= 1 and input <= 4
        loop: go through array from 0 to counter
            if element at array = input
                alert user
                break loop
            else if element at array is < 1 or > 4
                set element as input
                increment counter
                break loop
while input < 1 or input > 4 or counter < array length
```

And finally write the program using the pseudocode.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two problems I see:

1. you have an infinite loop:

   ```
   while(arr.length < 5)
   ```

   `arr.length` is 4, and 4 is always less than 5.
2. in your for loop, you execute `arr[j]=number;` as soon as you find one element of the array that is different from the entered number. That's wrong. You must only assign it if all the numbers are different from the entered number. And, I guess, you must store it in the first location not containing a number yet.

I advise you to cut the problem into several simplest parts, implemented as methods. For example, you could have a method `isNumberAlreadyInArray()`.

Answer (score 0):

A set of entered numbers would be much more logical in this situation

```
Set<Integer> inputs = new HashSet<>();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while(inputs.size() < 5) {
    Integer number = sc.nextInt();
    if(number <= 0 || number > 4) {
        // rejected
    }
    if(inputs.contains(number)) {
        // rejected
    }
    inputs.add(number);
}
```

Comment: The OP may be a beginner trying to understand *arrays*. Giving "answers" based on more advanced topics like `Set` or `ArrayList` is only going to confuse the OP further. You may casually mention advanced topics as alternatives for further study, but your answer should be based directly on the question, and on the same level.

Comment: @ADTC I disagree. Learning about more "logical" data structures like `List`, `Set` or `Map` gives the right *mindset* for programming. Once you want to actually learn how to implement them you look at arrays. It is with good reasons that programming languages are moving from arrays to more abstract data structures (Java 1.5+, Ruby, Python, Scala etc.). I would actually argue that Arrays are more complicated than `List`s or `Set`s

Comment: you are right but with a little modify to your code it works right.